# NameError: name 'BinanceAPIException' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to deal with python exceptions. In that case I'm working with the binance library and reading the [wiki](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html#binanceapiexception) I found the following

```
from binance.client import Client

try:
    client.get_all_orders()
except BinanceAPIException as e:
    print(e.status_code)
    print(e.message)
```

But If I only do this, I have the following error.

```
NameError: name 'BinanceAPIException' is not defined
```

I have to import something more? Maybe I have to define something previously?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing you import from `binance` is `Client`, from `binance.client`.  If you want `BinanceAPIException`, then you need to import that as well.  It won't be imported automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the specific exception class:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException # here

try:
    client.get_all_orders()
except BinanceAPIException as e:
    print(e.status_code)
    print(e.message)
```